# Are here any benefits from using std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, exception, unique-ptr

I stumbled upon code like this:

```
void foo(T* bar); // Note: takes ownership of 'bar'.

foo(new T());
```

And now I wonder if there is any point in refactoring it to:

```
void foo(T* bar); // Note: takes ownership of 'bar'.

auto tempT = std::make_unique<T>();
foo(tempT.release());
```

- Is it more exception-safe?
- It certainly adds a little bit more clarity regarding the transfer of ownership, though calling 'new' from the argument list already makes that very clear by itself.

Note that I unfortunately can't change the signature of 'foo'.

Comment: Same level of exception safety in current example.

Comment: What you have in mind narrows the window during which bad things can happen and could be avoided with a `unique_ptr`, but that window is tiny, so not by enough that I'd consider it a worthwhile improvement.

Comment: If I were to refactor this, I would create a wrapper function that takes a `std::unique_ptr` and then it releases it to `foo`.  This lets you have a call site like `auto ptr = std::make_unique<some_type>(args); ...; wrapper(std::move(ptr));`.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it more exception-safe?

No. However, consider a slightly more complex example:

```
auto tempT = std::make_unique<T>();
some_operation();
foo(tempT.release());
```

In this case, there would be a potential issue with exception safety if unique_ptr wasn't used.

That said, much safer would be:

```
void foo(std::unique_ptr<T> bar);  // no need to note that takes ownership
                                   // because that's implied by the type
```

> Note that I unfortunately can't change the signature of 'foo'.

Then write a wrapper function that you can control.

Comment: This is not the same example as OPs. You are injecting `some_operation` between creation of pointer and usage in `foo`, but OPs alternative is to use `new` in-place with calling `foo`.

Comment: @SergeyA `This is not the same example as OPs` Correct. It would be redundant to repeat OPs example here since OPs example is already in the question. `You are injecting some_operation between creation of pointer and usage in foo` Indeed. That's the part that slightly more complex than the original example. `OPs alternative is to use new in-place with calling foo.` That alternative wouldn't be an option in the more complex case where there is an operation between the allocation and the call to `foo`.

Comment: Yet your example is contrived. Your some operation does not depend on tempT, so injecting in between makes no sense. And once you start using tempT in some_operation, you end up with a completely different use-case. I think, OP's question is clear in that they have two reasonable alternatives (in-place new, or make_unique one line above) and they are asking which to prefer. Your answer does seem to be more general (i.e. why unique_ptr is better than naked pointer) than OP needs.

Comment: @SergeyA The post starts with an answer to OP's question. The more contrived example is presented separately from that.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not more exception safe.

But consider if function changes to take more parameters:

```
void foo(T* bar, T* more_bar = get_more_bar()); // Note: takes ownership of both.

foo(new T());
```

Now what if `get_more_bar()` is evaluated after `new T()` and throws.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider writing a wrapper for foo:

```
void wrap_foo(std::unique_ptr<T> arg) {
    foo(arg.get());
    arg.release();
}
```

If foo were to throw an exception without freeing the memory, this would free it.  However, if foo is already exception-safe and frees the memory before it throws an exception, this would free it twice.  Unfortuately there's no good way to write a safe wrapper for this that will detect if the memory has been released properly or not.

Comment: As soon as control enters `foo`, it becomes its job to free the pointer. IMO one shouldn't assume a function to be broken in this regard by default.

Comment: One frequently must deal with buggy existing libraries and work around their bugs, however.